# Xpath error with distinguished field

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, biztalk

In a transform shape within my message construct shape I can create an xslt with manually defined element values and have no issues. Now I add a message assignment shape after the transform and use my distinguished fields from my input schema but get the following error:

> A failure occurred while evaluating the distinguished field msgId against the message part data. The message part data does not contain at least one of the nodes specified by the XPath expression (listed below) that corresponds to the distinguished field. The cause for this error may be that the message part data has not been initialized or that the message part data does not conform to the message part schema. Ensure that the message part data is initialized correctly. XPath expression: `/*[local-name()='Input' and namespace-uri()='http://input.gfd.com']/*[local-name()='msgId' and namespace-uri()='']`

I have initialized the msgID field in my xslt map, yet the problem still persists: Am I missing anything?

```
Input.msgId = "c7a340a7e3e4c3fb0d9837a0800bb4e6";
```

Input Message (Message Part)

```
 <output:Output xsi:type="output:yOutput" xmlns:output="http://output.scv.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <outputType>Success</outputType>
                <Scv>
                     <msgId>c7a340a7e3e4c3fb0d9837a0800bb4e6</msgId>
                     <scvNum>14020082690001300</scvNum>
                </Scv>
    </output:Output>
```

At the moment though in my actual code I'm manually assigning the msgID.

Comment: Well, it's a beautifully clear message: what software does it come from? (You've tagged the question biztalk, is that relevant?) It suggests you look at the "message part data", which is what I would do next, if only you had shown us it.

Comment: edit: added the input message. yes this is biztalk

Comment: So the XML element <output:Output...> is your **input**?

Comment: The XPath expression is designed to examine a document whose outermost element is named "Input", whereas you've shown us a document whose outermos element is named "Output". Perhaps that's what the message is trying to say.

Comment: The reason why I was outputting my data into an input was because in the orchestration I must send an input to the server, I receive a output response back, then I must filter the output records, then finally send the data back to the server again.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. biztalk doesn't want to distinguish the correct msgId in the schema. I solved the issue by using the xpath syntax instead of using distinguished fields.